# Why CoCreateInstance can't create an instance of my component?

Tags: c++, com

I am learning COM through the book "Inside COM" of Dale Rogerson. I try to register my component in the registry and then through this info create an instance of my component in the code of my client. But I see `::FormatMessage` function writes this: *Class not registered*. So, `::CoCreateInstance` can't create an instance of my component.

My REG-file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{68584B56-9224-4DCC-AD35-1070CC9B8FDE}]
@="bush_component_01"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{68584B56-9224-4DCC-AD35-1070CC9B8FDE}\InprocServer32]
@="D:\\projects\\com_sandbox_solution_01\\Debug\\bush_component_01.dll"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{EB4BFC91-6A6E-43D1-B4CD-7A5DF24DB8D8}]
@="IID_IX"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{EB4BFC91-6A6E-43D1-B4CD-7A5DF24DB8D8}\InprocServer32]
@="D:\\projects\\com_sandbox_solution_01\\Debug\\bush_component_01.dll"
```

Piece of code of my client:

```
...
// GUID of my DLL (it registered in registry (look at my REG-code above))
// {68584B56-9224-4DCC-AD35-1070CC9B8FDE}
static const CLSID CLSID_component_01 =
{ 0x68584b56, 0x9224, 0x4dcc, { 0xad, 0x35, 0x10, 0x70, 0xcc, 0x9b, 0x8f, 0xde } };

// GUID of my some interface (it registered in registry (look at my REG-code above))
// {EB4BFC91-6A6E-43D1-B4CD-7A5DF24DB8D8}
static const IID IID_IX =
{ 0xeb4bfc91, 0x6a6e, 0x43d1, { 0xb4, 0xcd, 0x7a, 0x5d, 0xf2, 0x4d, 0xb8, 0xd8 } };
...

// Code of my client:

 ::CoInitialize(nullptr);

  IUnknown* comp = nullptr;
  HRESULT hcri = ::CoCreateInstance(CLSID_component_01, nullptr, 
    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IX, (void**)&comp);

  if (FAILED(hcri)){
    void* msg = nullptr;
    ::FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,
      nullptr, hcri, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPTSTR)&msg, 0,
      nullptr);
    trace("***** TRACE *****");
    trace((LPTSTR)msg);
    trace("****************");
    keep_window_open();
    return 1;
  }

// But ::FormatMessage function writes this: Class not registered
```

Why does it happen?

Comment: What i the values of `hcri`? Is your OS 64-bit, bitness of your server and client apps?

Comment: hcri = REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG. OS is 64-bit, MS Visual Studio 2013. I use a local machine for code writting and debugging at this case.

Comment: Your OS is 64-bit and you are using registry keys for 64-bit code. So your application and the DLL, are they 64-bit (x64 platform) as well?

Comment: Oh, I can't set x64 for all projects of my solution, because Visual Studio does it: http://s7.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2015/05/561f7a0d56a9ab42546c64349aa209ab.png But combobox of bush_component_01 bush_component_02 have not value for x64. It has win32 only.

Comment: Well, you possibly can do x64 if you uncheck the box, but let's skip it for now. 32-bit apps is okay as well, but in this case you need to use HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID instead of HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID in GraphEdit, you need the [registry key for 32-bit world](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724072). You don't have it in the book because it was published before x64 emerged at all...

Comment: To me tell how to make x64 for three projects. I did it now. But now I get an exception: "Unhandled exception at 0x000000013F5F5733 in bush_client_01.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000."

Comment: Thank you, @Roman R. Now I use the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID` key. I get  other error now: "Error in the DLL". I will look for a problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 64-bit Windows 32-bit applications should use [`Wow6432Node`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724072) registry subkey (in terms of 64-bit regedit).

Unfortunately 32-bit book does not cover that.